# Why Does Text Markup Size Varies Based on Zoom?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When loading text markups from a database, the text markups show up in a different size based on the current zoom of the viewer. How do I make text markups show at a static size regardless of zoom?

```
function saveFreeformMarkup(markup){
  let markupObject = {
    x: markup.position.x,
    y: markup.position.y,
    width: markup.size.x,
    height:markup.size.y,
    type: TEXT_MARKUP_TYPE,
    text: $(`#freeText`).val(),
    urn_id: urn[`id`],
    active: ACTIVE
  };
  $.ajax({
    ... send markupObject to database ...
  });
}
```

```
function loadSingleMarkup(markup, markupTool){
  let MarkupsCore = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core;
  let text = new MarkupsCore.MarkupText(markup.id + ID_INCREMENT, markupTool, markup.text);
  markupTool.addMarkup(text);
  text.setSize({ x: markup.x, y: markup.y}, markup.width, markup.height);
  text.setText(markup.text);
  text.updateStyle(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the `loadSingleMarkup()` function to the following

```
const FONT_SIZE_SCALE = 90;
function loadSingleMarkup(markup, markupTool){
  let MarkupsCore = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core;
  let text = new MarkupsCore.MarkupText(markup.id + ID_INCREMENT, markupTool, markup.text);
  markupTool.addMarkup(text);
  text.setSize({ x: markup.x, y: markup.y}, markup.width, markup.height);
  text.setText(markup.text);
  text.style[`font-size`] = 12 / FONT_SIZE_SCALE;
  text.updateStyle(true);
}
```

(adding `` text.style[`font-size`] = 12 / FONT_SIZE_SCALE; ``)

Answer (score 0):

This is because there's an handler attached to the camera change event that adjusts the `viewbox` of the SVG per the updated bounds of the current view when navigation (scaling/panning) occurs.

To overcome this you can piggyback the `onCameraChange` handler of the MarkupCore extension (be sure to do this prior to the event binding to the upper chain that is before entering the edit mode) and apply scaling to the SVG based on the current camera pivot values and the ones recorded when you added the markups:

```
MarkupsCore.originalOnCameraChange = MarkupsCore.onCameraChange;
MarkupsCore.onCameraChange = function(event){
   let scaleString = calculateScale(originalPivot, viewer.autocam.pivot);
   this.svg.setAttribute('transform', scaleString);
   this.originalOnCameraChange(event)
}
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) for details on SVG transform.

Will leave it up to you to implement the calculations or even a better approach to transform the markups in response to navigation.

Comment: You use a variable titled `originalPivot` and a function called `calculateScale` in your code snippet. Is the variable something that I need to be storing when I create the markups or is that part of the Forge API? Is that function something I need to create or is that part of the API?

Comment: Yes you will need to implement `calculateScale` to map the pivot value changes as the camera zooms in/out to SVG scaling settings and record the original pivot values as `originalPivot` (or whatever you’d name the variable after)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was actually able to find a simpler work around to solve this issue by digging around in the source code for the MarkupsCore Extension